# What's the difference between zend_string_release and zend_string_free?

Tags: c, php-internals

I saw the [source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_string.h#L195-L210), but still can't explain the diff with total confidence:

```
static zend_always_inline void zend_string_free(zend_string *s)
{
    if (!IS_INTERNED(s)) {
        ZEND_ASSERT(GC_REFCOUNT(s) <= 1);
        pefree(s, GC_FLAGS(s) & IS_STR_PERSISTENT);
    }
}

static zend_always_inline void zend_string_release(zend_string *s)
{
    if (!IS_INTERNED(s)) {
        if (--GC_REFCOUNT(s) == 0) {
            pefree(s, GC_FLAGS(s) & IS_STR_PERSISTENT);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Would be nice to have a practical example where `zend_string_free` would be more appropriate than `zend_string_release` or vice versa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`zend_string`s are reference counted. This means that multiple places can use the same `zend_string` simply by incrementing its refcount. This is done using either `zend_string_copy` or `zend_string_addref`.

The `zend_string_release` function, which is what you want to use in the vast majority of cases, will decrement the refcount. If it so happens that you were the last user of the string (i.e. the refcount is now zero) the string will be deallocated.

The `zend_string_free` function is an optimization for the cases where you already *know* that you're the only one using the string. It will directly free the string, without checking the refcount first (the assert is only there for debugging, it is not present in release builds).

When in doubt, use `zend_string_release`.